# WebSocket connection to 'wss:<XXX...azure-devices.net/'> failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: node.js, azure, ionic-framework

I am trying to use the `azure-iot-device-mqtt` in the application. I am trying to connect to the `azure iot hub`. Following is the code I am using. But whenever I am trying to connect I get the error

> 'WebSocket connection to 'wss: failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400'. Can anyone guide me to fix this?

```
var Mqtt = require('azure-iot-device-mqtt').Mqtt; 
var DeviceClient = require('azure-iot-device').Client;
var connectionString = config.hubConnectionString; 
var client = DeviceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString, Mqtt); 

// Connect to the IoT hub. 
client.open(function (err) { 
  if (err) { 
     console.log('Could not connect: ' + err); 
  } else { 
     console.log('Client connected'); 
  } 
client.close(function() { 
  process.exit(0); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. If I use the azure-iot-device-mqtt node module in a node program, it works just fine. Trying to add the same code to a react app, fails with the same error you are getting. Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on my side and it works for me . I am not sure if you missed something,as 400 error likely arguments error.

Anyway , these are the steps I made the code work :

1. Create a Iot hub.
2. Register a device here by default and note the deviceID:
   [image]
3. find connection string here and use it in your code :
   [image]

   4. Config the value of `connectionString` , you should append "DeviceId=<-deviceID value in step2->" to your connection string : 
      [image]

Hope it helps .

Comment: Hi , pls click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to mark this answer if my solution is helpful so that this answer will help others have similar issues . If you have any further concerns , pls feel free to let me know : )